# PHP upload_max_filesize different values from phpinfo()

Tags: php, apache2

I am trying to setup Apache and PHP on Amazon Linux AMI.

I installed `PHP 7.2.5` and `Apache`.

I want to be able to upload files upto `100M`, so i edited the `/etc/php.ini` file and set

```
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 100M
```

Then i tried to output `phpinfo` using Apache and cli.

Here are the contents of the file:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

The same file when executed through `Apache` shows `upload_max_filesize` as 2M.

When executed through the command line  as:
`php info.php | grep -i "upload_max_filezize"`

outputs

`upload_max_filesize => 100M => 100M`

Output in both the cases points to the same `php.ini` file, which is where i have defined the max file upload size.

What is it that i am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you restart your apache afterwards?

Comment: Are the cli and apache-php config the same file? They might be different files. You can check from the output of phpinfo();

Comment: @Broco Yes, i did

Comment: @eKKiM Are we talking about the `php.ini` or something else? The outputs point to the same `php.ini`. If it is a different file, what should i look for?

Comment: @ShikharChauhan look in phpinfo() what the exact path is to php.ini. Its likely not "/etc/php.ini", but somewhere else. Edit that file